# how to know which field is change in formbuilder angular2

Tags: angular

how to know which field is change in form builder angular2,
i want to add some checking if field a is change the do what if field b is change do this

```
this.comparisonForm = this.formBuilder.group({
        city: ['', [Validators.required]],
        brand: ['', [Validators.required]],
        productTemplate: ['', [Validators.required]],
        productAttributeValue: ['', [Validators.required]],
    });

this.comparisonForm.valueChanges
    .debounceTime(500)
    .subscribe(keyword => 
        console.log(keyword));
```

Comment: Your question is extremely unclear. Please reword it so it is clearer

Answer (score 0):

I had same problem and end up subscribing to each field.

```
this.comparisonForm['city']
.valueChanges 
.debounceTime(500)
.subscribe(value => console.log(value));
```

Comment: yeah i end up using this method too,

Comment: @kazuyahiko At some point it make sense since formgroup it just abstract control https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/2.4.8/modules/%40angular/forms/src/model.ts#L843